# Change values in table using coronaSDK in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, prepend

I'm making a game using CoronaSDK and I have a question
I have a table with 72 indexes and another table with 6

I must remove the latest 72 indexes and "prepend" the 6 in another table

Variables:
- blockList (has 72)
- extraLine (has 6)

I'm trying to make this:

```lua
function Board:addExtraLine()
    -- Change latest to latest-6 until 6
    for i=12*6, 7, 1 do
        self.blockList[i] = self.blockList[i-6]
    end

    -- This doesnt work
    for i=1, 6, 1 do
      self.blockList[i].value = self.extraLine[i].value + 0
      self.blockList[i].y = 1
    end

    self.extraLine = {}
end
```

I think that I'm changing the C pointer instead of the value, but I have no idea how can I fix this.

Someone can help me?

Comment: this is written wrong `for i=12*6, 7, 1 do`, should be `for i=7, 12*6, 1 do`. currently your first `for` loop will never execute as it is immediately completed

Answer (score 0):

Solved using table.insert

```lua
function Board:addExtraLine()
    -- Change latest to latest-6 until 6
    for i=12*6, 7, 1 do
        self.blockList[i] = self.blockList[i-6]
    end

    -- This doesnt work
    for i=1, 6, 1 do
      table.insert(self.blockList, i, self.extraLine[i])
      self.blockList[i].y = 1
    end

    self.extraLine = {}
end
```

Thanks for this

Comment: But why do you need `for i=12*6, 7, 1 do` then? This loop body will never be executed, because 12*6 is larger than 7

Probably you want to remove this for